# How to connect multiple BLE devices in Android?

Tags: android-fragments, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-activityrecord

I am currently working on andriod Bluetooth Low Energy, I am able to connect to a first BLE device and get services, read/write service, and when i try to connect to second device, it connects for 15-20 sec and then disconnects. Now when i try to connect to write/read characteristic of first device, nothing works.

Has any one tried connecting to multiple devices. How do you initialize Gatt for multiple devices(minimum 5 devices)?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your hardware how many devices you can connect stable.I recomment you to use on seperate service for the scanning part and one Data exchange Service for the each of your devices. For the data exchange service don't use bind service. This gave me connection handling problems. I recommend you to create a List of Strings with the Macadresses you are looking for. When you found one, delete it from you List and transmit the found device to the it's service. You should also have a look at disconnecting. Stop service and in it's `onDestroy` call

```
 mConnectedGatt.disconnect();
        ble_device=null;
```